# List of lists of lists into a data frame with purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Suppose we have the following list structure:

```
bla <- list(lda = list(list(auc1 = 0.85, auc2 = 0.56), list(auc1 = 0.65, auc2 = 0.72)),
            j48 = list(list(auc1 = 0.99, auc2 = 0.81), list(auc1 = 0.61, auc2 = 0.85)),
            c50 = list(list(auc1 = 0.92, auc2 = 0.59), list(auc1 = 0.68, auc2 = 0.80)))
```

The desired output is a data frame structured as:

```
    auc1 auc2
lda 0.85 0.56
lda 0.65 0.72
j48 0.99 0.81
j48 0.61 0.85
c50 0.92 0.59
c50 0.68 0.80
```

My attempt is pasted below. I'm able to purrr each inner list separately using the call:

```
bla[[1]] %>%
    map(., function(x) c(auc1 = x[["auc1"]],
                         auc2 = x[["auc2"]])) %>%
    map_dfr(., as.list)
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly only using `bind_rows` gives you what you want.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(bla)
```

This returns a tibble and tibbles don't have rownames.

---

You can do this in base R using `do.call` + `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, unlist(bla, recursive = FALSE))


#     auc1 auc2
#lda1 0.85 0.56
#lda2 0.65 0.72
#j481 0.99 0.81
#j482 0.61 0.85
#c501 0.92 0.59
#c502 0.68 0.8
```

Comment: `Error: Argument 1 must have names`

Comment: @Andrej I think you have old `dplyr`, works fine on `1.0.0`. Can you update it and check? I also added a base R option.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(bla)
```